# React Big Calendar style dates which have events

Tags: reactjs, customization, react-big-calendar

I would like to change the style of dates in my month calendar view which have events.

This is the design I'm developing:

[image]

So I need to change style of `.rbc-date-cell` to blue for each date with an event. I have searched high and low for a solution to this, most commonly I find examples for creating a CustomDateCell for dateCellWrapper which will conditionally style cells, here's one example I've tried:

[React Big Calendar how to style a single day in the month view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921832/react-big-calendar-how-to-style-a-single-day-in-the-month-view)

This changes the style of `.rbc-day-bg` not `.rbc-date-cell`. The markup on RBC is complex, because the devs made it for events which can stretch over multiple days. This means that the background divs are in a different parent to the datecells. I'd prefer not to traverse/manipulate the DOM to style these cells.

**Surely there must be a way to style the datecells?** the docs and all answers I've found on SO and github haven't yielded anything so far. Could it be done with `eventPropGetter`?

**EDIT**

The HTML is as follows. I've also tried custom slot props and eventPropgetter but have not been able to directly manipulate the rendering of .rbc-date-cell

```html
<div class="rbc-month-row">
  <div class="rbc-row-bg">
    <div class="rbc-day-bg" style="background-color: lightgreen;"></div>
    <div class="rbc-day-bg" style="background-color: lightgreen;"></div>
    <div class="rbc-day-bg rbc-today" style="background-color: lightgreen;"></div>
    <div class="rbc-day-bg" style="background-color: lightblue;"></div>
    <div class="rbc-day-bg" style="background-color: lightblue;"></div>
    <div class="rbc-day-bg" style="background-color: lightblue;"></div>
    <div class="rbc-day-bg" style="background-color: lightblue;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rbc-row-content">
    <div class="rbc-row">
      <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">13</a></div>
      <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">14</a></div>
      <div class="rbc-date-cell rbc-now rbc-current"><a href="#">15</a></div>
      <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">16</a></div>
      <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">17</a></div>
      <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">18</a></div>
      <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">19</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

rbc-event's exist in a different row to the rbc-date-cell, in this markup there are events on the 23rd and 24th. I don't want to traverse the DOM to conditionally style divs as this isn't a very React way of doing things, it should be done before rendering if possible

```html
<div class="rbc-row-content">
  <div class="rbc-row ">
    <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">21</a></div>
    <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">22</a></div>
    <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">23</a></div>
    <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">24</a></div>
    <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">25</a></div>
    <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">26</a></div>
    <div class="rbc-date-cell"><a href="#">27</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rbc-row">
    <div class="rbc-row-segment" style="flex-basis: 28.5714%; max-width: 28.5714%;"> </div>
    <div class="rbc-row-segment" style="flex-basis: 14.2857%; max-width: 14.2857%;"><button class="rbc-event"><div class="rbc-event-content" title="2/2"><p class="event-wrapper">2/2</p></div></button></div>
    <div class="rbc-row-segment" style="flex-basis: 14.2857%; max-width: 14.2857%;"><button class="rbc-event"><div class="rbc-event-content" title="1/1"><p class="event-wrapper">1/1</p></div></button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: row]

Comment: What code have you tried? The complex HTML you refer to should be in the question itself. Running code is always better than a paragraph. Clone https://codesandbox.io/s/jp1931172w and explain what you have tried and how it's not working.

Comment: @JuanMendes I have tried creating a custom date cell the same way as shown in that codesandbox, I've also tried custom slot props and eventPropgetter but have not been able to directly manipulate the rendering of .rbc-date-cell

Comment: Is the styling added via a special class name or using style={} either way i think you can do a check if each of the rendered cells have an event and if so change the style , class name accordingly. For example `<div className={"rbc-date-cell " + (hasEvent ? 'specialStyleClass' : '')}>`.

Comment: @Muljayan updated my question to show events markup

Comment: Are you generating these codes manually or over a list of calendar date ? Also is there a  state or prop which gives which dates have events ?

Comment: @Muljayan these are generated by the react-big-calendar plugin, I pass an events prop which generates the events `events={this.state.events}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

checkout this sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/73ky8rj2qj
if that's what you want to achieve so the main idea is to override month `dateHeader` and then with every dateHeader to render check if its `date` prop is between any event `startDate` and `endDate` and render it with the desired style

Comment: thank you @SerenityTn!!! this is exactly what I was looking for. This is not in the docs